# Placing divs side by side with embedded map and hidden overflow

Tags: html, css

How can I place the map and caption side by side? I wouldn't care if the caption dropped below with a narrow screen but otherwise they should really be side by side. I'll even take alternative layout suggestions.

There are many questions and answers about placing divs side by side, and after reading and attempting many of them I'm still not getting it to work. This is what I have so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/uun9hyfg/1/

CSS

```
.map_and_caption
{
    width: 700px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.map
{
    width:470px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.caption
{
    width:230px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    height: 200px;
    float: right;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="map_and_caption">
    <div class="map">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed" width="800" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
        <h2>Best Price, Great Location</h2>
        <p>We are located inside of the office of Dr. Joe Shmo and a Happy Place. With a comfortable atmosphere we attend you with the warmth of a Happy Place and the professionality of a medical office.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is the container does not have enough width to hold the two elements inside, I also simplified the CSS code.

http://jsfiddle.net/uun9hyfg/2/

```
.map_and_caption {
    width: 700px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
}
.map {
    width:470px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.caption {
    width:200px;
    float: left;
}
.map iframe {
    max-width: 100%
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to keep the hidden overflow on the map, but was able to do that by keeping overflow:hidden on .map and changing the width on the .map iframe to 160%. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS should be like this:

```
.map_and_caption
{
    width: 700px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.map
{
    width:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
}
.caption
{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    float: right;
}
```

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/erickcortorreal/gsw9wdac/1/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you know how to place them side by side?